# Materialize.css selectbox rendering duplicate select boxes

Tags: css, select, materialize

I am using Materialize.css library (v 1.0.0), as of 2018 for my project to add the material components. However, I failed to initialize two select boxes with it.

I have two select boxes in my page.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#numPagesPaginate").formSelect();
  $("#numRatingsEdit").formSelect();
});
```

```html
<select id="numPagesPaginate" name="numPagesPaginate" data-ng-model="bkCtrl.page.pageSize">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<select id="numRatingsEdit" name="numRatingsEdit" style="display:none">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

However, when I initialize both the select boxes using this only the first one works.

In addition, if I initialize the second selectbox in the script tag elsewhere, the box gets initialized and works, but there is one duplicate selectbox.

Edited: To add this question, I want to tell you that I have read the documentation and the default method. However, no results.

Answer (score -1):

You should [follow documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization) and initialize globally with one line:

```
$('select').formSelect();
```

Comment: I have read the documentation thoroughly, and used the above as the first method. However, the problem still persists.

Answer (score -1):

Just like Serg said, you should follow the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization) properly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            <label>Num Pages Paginate</label>
            <select id="numPagesPaginate" name="numPagesPaginate" data-ng-model="bkCtrl.page.pageSize">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6">
            <label>Num Ratings Edit</label>
            <select id="numRatingsEdit" name="numRatingsEdit">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').formSelect();
    });
</script>
```